# Serializing an SQL Function in Django REST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm using Django and Django Rest Framework to build an API.

I have a custom PostgreSQL function like this: `myfunction(from_date, to_date)`

It simply calculates a figure from records in the date range in `reviews` table.

How can I (*safely!*) take `from_date` and `to_date` from URL query parameters, pass them to the function, and return the (float) result via the API?

I have made a simple model to hold the float, like this:

```
class Result(models.Model):
result = models.FloatField(default=0)

class Meta:
    managed = False
```

Alternatively, could I forgo the SQL function and implement this directly in Django/REST itself?

I already have a model for `reviews`. In the view for `result` can I pull `reviews` from a date range, calculate it, and return the value as a serialized `result` response?

As an end result, I want to be able to curl `http://my.api/result?from=2019-03-01&to=2019-04-01` and get the `result`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can just simple filtering with [lte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#lte) and [gte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#gte) in your `review` Model and i am supposing `date` is a field of your `Review` model where you store record of every review. Then

```
Review.objects.filter(date__gte=from_date, date__lte=to_date)
```

Replace date with appropriate field name of your `Review` model And also with appropriate serializer.